# Blazor Hosted WebApp - Error after publishing

Tags: web-hosting, blazor-webassembly

I have started learning Blazor Webassembly using the Hosted model.

Locally I can create and run a simple Blazor web application using visual studio code.

However, when I publish (in this case to [www.myasp.net](http://www.myasp.net)) the following scripting error occurs on any page:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
Unhandled exception rendering component: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () <0x21ea748 + 0x0002c> in :0
at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync (Microsoft.JSInterop.IJSRuntime jsRuntime, System.String identifier, System.Object[] args) <0x2010058 + 0x000e4> in :0
at

Thank you

Here is the full error:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
Unhandled exception rendering component: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () <0x21ea748 + 0x0002c> in <filename unknown>:0  at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeVoidAsync (Microsoft.JSInterop.IJSRuntime jsRuntime, System.String identifier, System.Object[] args) <0x2010058 + 0x000e4> in <filename unknown>:0  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationService`3[TRemoteAuthenticationState,TAccount,TProviderOptions].EnsureAuthService () <0x20084c0 + 0x000ee> in :0
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationService`3[TRemoteAuthenticationState,TAccount,TProviderOptions].GetAuthenticatedUser () <0x2007c20 + 0x000d2> in <filename unknown>:0  at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () <0x21ebf88 + 0x0002c> in :0
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationService`3[TRemoteAuthenticationState,TAccount,TProviderOptions].GetUser (System.Boolean useCache) <0x1fcb190 + 0x00136> in <filename unknown>:0  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationService`3[TRemoteAuthenticationState,TAccount,TProviderOptions].GetAuthenticationStateAsync () <0x1fc9ff0 + 0x000d0> in :0
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthorizeViewCore.OnParametersSetAsync () <0x2135338 + 0x0012e> in :0
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x2135d90 + 0x000ee> in :0
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync () <0x1f67eb0 + 0x0020c> in :0
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask (System.Threading.Tasks.Task taskToHandle) <0x21391a0 + 0x000ca> in :0

Comment: here is the full error:

Comment: Care to share how you fixed it?

Comment: Have you fixed it. Please share your fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,

1. The hosting provider granted the application pool full access to the root folder (the folder just beneath the wwwroot folder) This solved the problem for me.
2. Since I am forcing my website to use https I also had to obtain a .pfx copy of my certificate with a private key - which I then include in the appsettings.json file

```
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "xxxxxxxxx.Client": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      }
    },

    "Key": {
      "Type": "File",
      "FilePath": "xxxxxxxxx.pfx",
      "Password": "xxxxxxxxx"
    }      
  }
```